# Mocha test report customize xunit reporter

Tags: mocha.js

In xunit reporter of mocha, it generates the report for attributes tests, failures, skipped, error. but i want for mocha's pending, dropped and blocked reports also. is these reports are generated using xunit? can we customize the xunit reporter to generate the report which has

```
 pending
 dropped
 blocked
```

test cases report. please help me to find solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue and pending tests have been added to the xunit reporter.

First are you using the latest version of mocha?

https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/1051/files that pull request has been merged into the latest version of mocha and should including pending requests in xunit?

You can always fork mocha and edit lib/reporters/xunit.js and add

```
runner.on('dropped', function(test){
   tests.push(test);
});
runner.on('blocked', function(test){
   tests.push(test);
});
```

Or instead of forking mocha. Copy Xunit and make a custom mocha reporter. You can use https://github.com/startswithaj/mocha-spec-cov as a template.

Comment: thanks. yes i am using latest version of mocha 1.18.2. i tried by adding runner.on code part as mentioned above and tested with my code. in the generated xml file i can see like this tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" dropped="undefined" pending="0" blocked="undefined". how to initialize the values for these new attributes i analyzed the code part, but i coudlnt find were to initialize these attributes.

Comment: I searched the mocha source and realised that mocha doesn't have test states 'blocked' or 'dropped', only 'pass', 'fail' and 'pending'. You would need to extend the most base test runner to support these states.